# Rendering output from user in javascript

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I'm learning web development and I am struggling with JavaScript.

I have a web page that will give frequency details from an entered frequency, but I cannot work out how to make the `if-statement` work.

Below is the HTML and below that is the JavaScript.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Radio Frequency Assistant</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <nav class="navbar">
      <h1>Radio Frequency Assistant</h1>
      <p>Helping to tune you in!</p>
    </nav>
    
    <div class="main">
        <div class="top">
          <div class="innerTop"><p></p></div>

          <div class="innerTop">
            <label>Enter a Value</label>
            <input name="freq" id="freq" type="text" size="10" placeholder="example 3.0254">
          </div>

          <div class="innerTop">
            <label>Choose Frequency</label>
            <form class="hertz">
              <select id="hertz">
                <option value="Hz">Hz</option>
                <option value="kHz">kHz</option>
                <option value="MHz">MHz</option>
                <option value="GHz">GHz</option>
                <option value="THz">THz</option>
              </select>
            </form>
          </div>

          <div class="innerTop">
            <button onclick="freqDetails()">Frequency Details</button>
          </div>

        </div><!-- top -->

        <div class="middle"></div><!-- middle -->

        <div class="bottom">
          <div class="innerBottom">
            <h3>Frequency Range</h3>
            <p>Top and Bottom Value</p>
            <p> Selected: <span id="enteredValue"> </span></p>
            <p> Range: <span id="freqRange"> </span></p>
          </div>

          <div class="innerBottom">
            <h3>Wavelength Range</h3>
            <p>Length of the Wave</p>
            <span id="waveRange"> </span>
          </div>

          <div class="innerBottom">
            <h3>Frequency</h3>
            <p>Band Information</p>
            <span id="bandRange"> </span>
          </div>

          <div class="innerBottom">
            <h3>Propagation</h3>
            <p>Type Used</p>
            <span id="prop"> </span>
          </div>
        </div><!-- bottom -->
      </div>
  
  </body>
</html>
```

My Javascript:

```
function freqDetails()
{ 
    document.getElementById('enteredValue').innerHTML = 
        document.getElementById("freq").value +
        document.getElementById("hertz").value;

    var freq = enteredValue;
    if(freq <= '30kHz'){
        document.getElementById('freqRange').innerHTML = '3-30kHz';
        document.getElementById('waveRange').innerHTML = '100-1km';
        document.getElementById('bandRange').innerHTML = 'VLF';
        document.getElementById('prop').innerHTML = 'Ground Wave';
    }
}
```

All assistance is appreciated.

Comment: You are trying to evaluate using a numerical operation on a string, not a number. Remove the unit `kHz` from the value you want compare, so you are evaluating just the number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem resides in the check

```
if(freq <= '30kHz')
```

a numerical comparison cannot be performed on strings containing alphabetic digits, even if they are "homogeneous" (e.g. `23kHz < 30kHz`).

You first need to convert the frequency to a numerical value.

This function does the job:

```
function freqDetails()
{
  var numFreq = document.getElementById("freq").value;
  var unit    = document.getElementById("hertz").value;
  var freq;
  
  document.getElementById('enteredValue').innerHTML = numFreq + unit;
  
  switch(unit)
  {     
      case "kHz":
        freq = 1000 * numFreq;
        break;
        
      case "MHz":
        freq = 1000000 * numFreq;
        break;
        
      case "GHz":
        freq = 1000000000 * numFreq;
        break;
        
      case "THz":
        freq = 1000000000000 * numFreq;
        break;
        
      case "Hz":
      default: /* We set "Hz" as the fallback case even if it should never occur */
        freq = numFreq;
        break;
  }
  
  if(freq <= 30000)
  {
    document.getElementById('freqRange').innerHTML = '3-30kHz';
    document.getElementById('waveRange').innerHTML = '100-1km';
    document.getElementById('bandRange').innerHTML = 'VLF';
    document.getElementById('prop').innerHTML = 'Ground Wave';
  }
  else
  {
    document.getElementById('freqRange').innerHTML = '';
    document.getElementById('waveRange').innerHTML = '';
    document.getElementById('bandRange').innerHTML = '';
    document.getElementById('prop').innerHTML = '';
  }
}
```

---

**Description:**

1. First of all store the numerical value and the unit in two different variables (`numFreq` and `unit`). You will concatenate them to fill `enteredValue` span as already used to do.
2. With a `switch-case` statement, calculate the real numerical frequency value (`freq`) according to the value of `numFreq` and `unit`. You are currently checking against only 30kHz, but as a general rule it is correct to convert correctly also GHz and THz values.
3. Perform the **correct numerical check**: `if(freq <= 30000)` - since you have `freq` in hertz, compare it with 30kHz in Hz.
4. Make sure to have an `else` in which you empty the values in case the frequency goes back under the 30kHz threshold.

Comment: Thank you Roberto Caboni, Much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Are the units always in kHz?

Because you will need to covert the input data, which is a string, into a number.
Then you can do numerical comparison on the data. If the units can vary however, this becomes a little harder.

If the unit is always kHz, it should be as simple as:

```js
var freq = parseFloat(enteredValue);
if(freq <= 30){
    // ...
}
```

If units can vary, it's a little harder but something like this should work:

```js
var units = {kHz: 1000, Hz: 1}; // Augment this list will all supported units
var unit = enteredValue.match(/\d*\s*(\w*)\s*/);
var scalar = units[unit[1]] || 1;
var freq = parseFloat(enteredValue) * scalar;
if(freq <= 30 * 1000){ // * 1000 to express in Hertz
    // ...
}
```

Hope this solves your issue.

Comment: Thank you TarVK, Much appreciated!